# Structure initialization (user defined types and primitives)?

Tags: c++, qt, struct

Example:

```
struct myStruct          //Structure definition
{
    int intPrimitive;
    QStringList object;
};

struct myStruct helloStruct;   //Structure creation
```

From my current understanding, if no initialization is done to the `intPrimitive` it will contain a random value from the memory location that was given to the variable.

Will a default constructor be called like when defining one in a class? What if the objects  constructor requires attributes (and should be initialized that way for each struct)?

Comment: If the `helloStruct` variable is declared as a local non-static variable, it will not be initialized. And the value of uninitialized data is *indeterminate* and not random, it will just *seem* to be random. Reading uninitialized data leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: There is no need to specify `struct` when you declare the `helloStruct;` variable. `mystruct helloStruct` is all you need to do.

Comment: "objects and primitives" should be "user defined types and primitives".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default constructor will be called that will ,in this case, create an empty QStringList.

```
struct myStruct
{
    int intPrimitive;
    QStringList object;
};

struct myStruct helloStruct;
qDebug() << myStruct.object;           // ()
qDebug() << myStruct.intPrimitive;     //  1
```

NOTE:
Don't know the last answer yet. Please edit the answer if you know, I've made it a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, if you provide *any* kind of constructor, the compiler will not generate a default constructor for you.

If you have a special constructor that needs arguments, you should also create the default constructor if it should be possible to create an instance without arguments.

Example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    Foo(int aa) : a(aa) {}
};

Foo foo1(123);  // Okay, uses the special constructor
Foo foo2;       // Error, no default constructor
```